# Enzyme shallow testing with Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm using Material UI in my application.  I have the following component that I want to test for a valid disclaimer text (notice that I'm using the withStyles HOC here):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { object } from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

const headerBarHeight = 64;

const styles = () => ({
    disclaimer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: headerBarHeight,
        padding: '0 0 5px 10px'
    }
});

const Disclaimer = props => {
    const { classes } = props;

    return (
        <div className={classes.disclaimer}>
            <Typography gutterBottom noWrap>
                Copyright StaticSphere { new Date().getFullYear() }
            </Typography>
        </div>
    );
};

Disclaimer.propTypes = {
    classes: object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Disclaimer);
```

What I'm trying to do is write a test that verifies the year is considered correctly:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

import Disclaimer from 'components/Shell/Disclaimer';

describe('Disclaimer', () => {
    it('displays the proper year', () => {
        var component = shallow(
            <Disclaimer />
        );

        var year = new Date().getFullYear();
        var text = component.find(Typography).text();

        expect(text).toBe(`Copyright StaticSphere ${year}`);
    });
});
```

This doesn't work.  The test complains that it can't find the Typography component.  Looking at the documentation, this is expected, since Typography isn't the root component.  When I change the test to use mount, everything works.

That said, I've read that I should try and use shallow wherever possible, since mount creates an actual DOM to work with.  So, is there a better way to deal with this?  I've spent a day on the internet, and so far, haven't found a good example of a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `var text = component.dive().find(Typography).text();` ?

Comment: I tried various combinations of dive, and couldn't quite getting working the way I wanted.  I tried various versions of dive(), and couldn't quite get it working.  mount() works fine, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore HOC when testing React Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54630839/ignore-hoc-when-testing-react-components)

Answer (score 6):

OMG.... took me a while to make it work too but I've found a working example in the repo's page. `material-ui` has a wrapper on top of enzyme's `shallow` and `mount` that allows you to `dive` the component that you want to test.

`shallow = createShallow({ dive: true });` made my day.

This is [the config that I followed](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9266#issuecomment-355527161), also in my case I had to call `component.update();` after doing some operations in other to see my state updated.

Answer (score -2):

When you're using HOC we need to use `WrappedComponent` to get wrapped jsx inside it.

```
 var component = shallow(
        <Disclaimer.WrappedComponent />
    ).dive();
```

`dive() will further shallow re-render Components like in our case it's`Typegraphy`.

You can try this without using `dive()`

Apart from this you can simply access Typography with:

```
var text = component.find('withStyles(Typography)').text();
```

I hope this helps, let me know if the issue still persists

Comment: I tried various version of dive, and couldn't quite make it work,  Appreciate it, though.

Comment: Use WrappedComponent only

Comment: Share it over github. So easier to debug the problem