# Ignore HOC when testing React Components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I want to test a simple Material UI select form which uses a FormControl and is exported withStyles. My Test case is pretty simple, i want to assert for example that my  component renders an  child.
I try the following assertion:

```
expect(wrapper.find('InputLabel')).toEqual(true);
```

However, this assertion fails simply because the InputLabel is wrapped inside **WithStyles** *AND* **WithFromControlContext** (see debug output) :

```
<WithStyles(FormControl) id="my-control-id">
      <WithStyles(WithFormControlContext(InputLabel)) htmlFor="my-control-id">
        My Control Label
      </WithStyles(WithFormControlContext(InputLabel))>
      ...
    </WithStyles(FormControl)>
```

Is there any way to just test for the existence of the InputLabel child ignoring all the HOC components which are wrapped around it?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `wrapper.find()`, Enzyme offers [`wrapper.findWhere()`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/findWhere.html) - give it a function, and it returns every node in the render tree for which `fn(node) === true`.

(Not to be confused with `wrapper.filterWhere()`, which only looks at "the nodes of the current wrapper", which means direct children from what I can tell)

I whipped up this utility for my current project:

```js
const findWithStyles = (wrapper, name) => {
  // Only matches if there are no letters on either side
  // i.e.: Button, Styled(WithStyles(ForwardRef(Button)))
  // not:  MyButton, Buttons
  const matchExp = RegExp(`(?<![a-zA-Z])${name}(?![a-zA-Z])`);

  return wrapper.findWhere((node) => {
    const nodeName = node.name();

    // The extra check here is for raw HTML text, for which .name() is null
    return nodeName && nodeName.match(matchExp);
  });

  // Or, if your environment supports optional chaining (a?.b?.c):
  // return wrapper.findWhere(node => node.name()?.match(matchExp));
};

const buttons = findWithStyles(wrapper, 'Button');
```

Answer (score 0):

How i have done testing like this, with components that are wrapped in HOCs, is that i export both the wrapped component, and the non-wrapped component.

So, i have

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // All the code
}

export default withStyles(MyComponent);
```

So in my tests, i import the non-wrapped component with

```
import {MyComponent} from './MyComponent';
```

And in my code i import the default export

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
```

Comment: Not really into material-ui but named and default exports can make it easier to test.

Comment: That would help with the outer WithStyles, but what about the WithFromControlContext?

Comment: How do you mount the component in the test?

Comment: const shallow = createShallow({ dive: true });
    const wrapper = shallow(<SimpleSelect
        controlId="my-control-id"
        controlName="My Control Label"
        options={dummyOptions}
        onChange={handleChange} />);

Comment: I found [this](https://gist.github.com/fokusferit/e4558d384e4e9cab95d04e5f35d4f913) alittle comparison between `enzyme.mount(...)` and `enzyme.shallow(..)`

Comment: Could you for instance move the wrapper to the export line?
`export default withStyles(styles)(WithFormControlContext(InputLabel))`

Comment: The WithFormControlContext part I have no control over. in my component i only render a <FormControl> component. Material UI somehow adds the Context internally.

Comment: Could you set up a codepen for this? Really hard figure this out without having the code infront of me. :)

Comment: Allright, i would look into [createShallow](https://material-ui.com/guides/testing/#createshallow-options-shallow). And then `dive()`into the shallow component, to check if it contains a `InputLabel`.

Comment: Here's a code sandbox with the test working: https://codesandbox.io/s/lr1o8zwlz9 though I removed the TypeScript just because I'm not very familiar with it and didn't want to try to troubleshoot that aspect.